# Is authorization via Angular safe?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am completely new to Angular, and I was watching a tutorial where access to a 'dashboard' page was forbidden unless the user is logged in.

Code looks something like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {
    resolve: {
        check: function($location, user){
            if(!user.isUserLoggedIn()){
                $location.path('/404');
            }
        }
    }
    templateUrl: './dashboard.html',
    controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
})
```

What prevents a user from changing the above `if` statement (since, if I understand correctly, all of angular code is visible to the user) to `if(false){...}`, and therefore obtain access to the dashboard page?

I know that code is usually minified, but is that enough to prevent the user from finding a way to change it?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents the user from changing the JavaScript code on the client, even though it's minified.

You should prevent user from accessing the protected resources on the backend.

Comment: That's a general principle, not just for Angular.

Comment: Doesn't that make above code useless? What's the point of using Angular if  I have to implement the same logic on the server side to ensure the user is not doing any unwanted actions (not just regarding authorization, but all other actions contained within Angular controllers)?

Comment: @Marko it doesn't, because you define how your application should behave. There's nothing you can do on frontend to prevent that from happening and that's why you should do all your application-critical checks on backend.

Comment: Not sure why you think it's useless... The user will see a screen without data because he can't reach the protected source on the backend. You probably want to implement auth on the client for a better user experience.

Comment: @Dieterg It just seems to me that the above code is redundant, since I have to implement the check on the server side anyway, and I can redirect the user to /404 from server side as well.

Comment: @Marko how would you implement the redirect if you're using `ajax` calls? You could implement an `$http` interceptor which listens to `401 unauthorized` requests and do the redirect in the interceptor.

Comment: @Dieterg so basically angular does everything via ajax calls? If so, then maybe you can send the redirection url in the response and act upon it in the controller (as an alternative to your solution).

Comment: Yes if you're using angular's `$http` service!